# Do humans sneeze or cough in their sleep?

Tags: sleep

As far as I know, I've never seen anyone sneeze or cough while they're sleeping. Google wasn't very helpful either; a lot of contradicting claims.

So the questions remains: do humans sneeze or cough in their sleep? (a few other things I've never seen with sleeping people are yawning and vomiting) If they don't, why?

Comment: Babies may sneeze, cough and vomit while asleep, but it is not common even when they are ill. No reference, this is just my personal experience. I would think it's a matter of control over body muscles, babies have limited control (my kids would *very* often burp or sneeze and pass gas at the same time), but as they grow they learn to keep certain muscles in a certain state while asleep.

Comment: I've heard people sneezing and coughing in bed a lot. I can't be certain they were really asleep that moment though. They might have been woken up for just a minute by the discomfort that then caused the cough or sneeze.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sneezing does not occur during REM sleep, due to REM atonia.([1](http://scienceillustrated.com.au/blog/science/ask-us-can-humans-sneeze-while-sleeping/))

The coughing reflex is  also suppressed during sleep, but coughing may still occur occasionally during sleep. ([2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19823913)).